# How do I fix "class file contains wrong class"?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA and JDK 8.

I have some compiled Java Classes, and I imported them as an external library, as the code I have uses methods inside those classes. However, I can't seem to make actually use those .class files.

Whenever I try to run this code:

```
public static int spendOnCokes(int sum, DrinksMachineA mach) {
    int count = 0;
    mach.insert(sum);

    try {
        while (mach.getBalance() >= mach.getPrice()) {
            mach.pressCoke();
            count++;
        }
    } catch (EmptyMachineException e) {
    }
```

It gives me the following error:

```
    Error:(21, 45) java: cannot access com.sanac.DrinksMachineA
  bad class file: /homes/jmcv3/Documents/Java/ClassesArchive/com/sanac/DrinksMachineA.class
    class file contains wrong class: DrinksMachineA
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

I've searched around, and some people seemed to suggest that it had something to do with the folder hierarchy/package name. It looks fine to me though. I also tried switching to JDK 5 as that's what the .class file was compiled with, to no avail. (Also read that somewhere.)

Here's a screenshot outlining the directory structure:

[image: Structure]

All I want is to be able to use those compiled .class files with my code. Seems to be so simple, so I must be missing something really stupid. Any ideas?

Comment: You're likely missing this line at the beginning of your .java source file: `package com.sanac;`

Comment: provide all code in the file

Comment: Maybe it is what Endorphinex said.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: `.class` files aren't external libraries.

You can play with `jar.exe` Java tool to export "ClassesArchive" to a .jar file.

Answer (score 0):

File name and public class name should he same. Its a name issue by my perspective.